# Print out a log file with error from a cp command

Tags: cp, error-handling

I am writing an sh file
I have this command

```
cp test/*.txt NewDirectory/
```

from my understanding it will go one by one 
in the test folder

```
1.txt
2.txt
5.txt
6.txt
```

but won't copy

```
3.txt
4.txt
```

because they are not there

I need it to print out or in a log file the files it couldn't find or couldn't copy to the new folder.
How do I do that ?

Comment: It's quite unclear what you are asking for, so update your question and comment on already proposed answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding is incorrect. If there are only 1,2,5,6 there will be no error message in case those files are copied successfully. IF your need is to parse **N** number or txt files in folder and see which does not exist you can do something like: `for x in {1..10}; do cp $x.txt  NewDirectory/;done` .Further you can append `> output.log` to redirect the command output to file.

Answer (score 0):

with `cp test/*.txt NewDirectory/ 2>./output.log`

but the `cp` with * command will have to copy the files that exist and so do not show display error if files do not exist